# Differ single click and double click (outputLink & inlineEdit)

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport, outputlink

I am trying to something special on a Visualforce page.

I got a record name on a visualforce page and I want to open the record with a single click on this name. 
No problem with apex:outputLink. 

But additionally I want to inline edit (with apex:inlineEditSupport) this name by double clicking it.

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days/weeks I cancelled this approach. You can do this with some Javascript/JQuery magic, but the user experience suffers greatly.

Answer (score 0):

David,

You can put the apex:outputField in a apex:outputLink tag but you will likely get a clash between single click and double click.  Plus user experience may not be good if they want to edit and it opens the record.

You could wrap it around a label or something to distinguish between the single click and double click area.  This sample code should work for you if you want to go this route.

Sample Code Snippet:

```
    <apex:pageblocksectionItem >

    <apex:outputLink value="https://www.salesforce.com"> 

    Stage Label

    </apex:outputLink>               

    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>

    </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

    <apex:inlineEditSupport />
```

Good Luck!

William

Comment: You are right, but the user experience is very bad and noone want to use it.